# How can I store the currentState in react and set it again if something went wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, setstate

My problem is I can't keep the CurrentState when I update the post title, so when I throw an error to get the current state which is the state before I changed the post title I found that the current state also changed to the new state which is after I had changed the post title even I initialized it before the update!

I want just explanation for how it worked.

```
state = {
    posts: [],
  };

async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: posts } = await axios.get(apiEndPoint);
    this.setState({ posts });
  }

  handleUpdate = async (post) => {

    let currentState;
    currentState = this.state.posts;
    console.log(currentState[0].title);
    post.title = 'jsdhjs';

     try {
      await axios.put(apiEndPoint + '/' + post.id, post);
      throw new Error('');
    } catch (ex) {
      alert('Something Failed While Updating The Post');
      this.setState(currentState);
    }
  };

render(){
return(
          <tbody>
            {posts.map((post) => (
              <tr key={post.id}>
                <td>{post.title}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className='btn btn-info btn-sm'
                    onClick={() => this.handleUpdate(post)}
                  >
                    Update
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
       )

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the `title` of your old state.

```
currentState = this.state.posts;
```

This won't copy the posts of the current state, it will just store a reference to it in a local variable.

```
post.title = 'jsdhjs';
```

`post` in this case is also just a reference to one of the original posts in the current state - by setting the title, you will set the title in `currentState` as well, that's why "resetting" in the error case doesn't work.

To avoid this, make sure to not mutate anything within your state directly - only React should do that via `setState`.

In your case, one way would be to shallow-copy the post object before changing the title, e.g. by using the spread operator:

```js
const updatedPost = {
  ...post,
  title: 'jsdhjs',
};
// ...
await axios.put(apiEndPoint + '/' + updatedPost.id, updatedPost);
// TODO in success case, call this.setState with updatedPost
```

Also, it seems like you are calling `setState` with only the posts array while instead you should do `setState({ posts: currentState })` to keep the original shape. But maybe that's just a simplification for the question.

Comment: Omg Really Thank You !! I Appreciate the Time you wasted While Reading And Answering My Question Thank You Again !

Answer (score 0):

The reason your state got changed is because of how the mutations for objects work in javascript. For more info ref. [https://www.zeptobook.com/object-mutation-in-javascript/#:~:text=mutation%20in%20JavaScript.-,Object%20mutation%20in%20JavaScript,the%20reference%20to%20the%20value](https://www.zeptobook.com/object-mutation-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=mutation%20in%20JavaScript.-,Object%20mutation%20in%20JavaScript,the%20reference%20to%20the%20value).

You can update the `handleUpdate` function to this

```
  handleUpdate = async (post) => {
     try {
      await axios.put(apiEndPoint + '/' + post.id, {...this.state.posts[0], title: 'jsdhjs'});
      throw new Error('');
    } catch (ex) {
      alert('Something Failed While Updating The Post');
    }
  };
```

Then you won't have to care for reverting back to previous component state, because, you never mutated it.